# Tkinter using python. Why is *args needed here?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I've been messing around with tk today and I came across this piece of code from the official tutorial:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk 

def calculate(*args): 
       try: 
            value = float(feet.get()) 
            meters.set((0.3048 * value * 10000.0 + 0.5)/10000.0) 
       except ValueError: 
            pass

root = Tk() 
root.title("Feet to Meters") 

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12") 
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S)) 
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 

feet = StringVar() 
meters = StringVar() 
feet_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=feet) 
feet_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E)) 
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=meters).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command=calculate).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="feet").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W) 
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="is equivalent to").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="meters").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W) 

for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5) 

feet_entry.focus() 
root.bind('<Return>', calculate) 

root.mainloop()
```

I don't understand why the `*args` parameter in the calculate function is needed. If someone could explain it's use to me I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `calculate` is a callback function that may take arguments. You don't actually need to use `*args` (you could specify exactly how many and which parameters it takes), but using `*args` is a common convention when you don't care what they are -- this allows the callback to take any number of arguments without causing an error.

Comment: The thing is that I don't get where the parameters come into place. The function shouldn't need any parameters passed to it. Maybe it's a python thing I don't understand.

Comment: The button `command` callback doesn't produce any parameters but the `bind` callback does -- it passes an event representing what happened. More information about events here:  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. Thanks for the fast reply!

Answer (score 0):

The python `*arg` pattern allow to access arguments of a method through an array (if calling `calculate(1, "foo")`, arg would be `[1, "foo"]`)<sup>1</sup>. It is the python way to implement [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

Here, `calculate` callback is used in two bindings, first with `Button(..., command=calculate)` which expect a callback to be called without argument, second with  `root.bind('<Return>', calculate)` that will call calculate with an event object as argument. Making calculate a variadic function allow to use the same function, sometimes called without argument, at other times called with one argument.

Not using this pattern would either lead to one of this type errors:

```
TypeError: calculate() takes no arguments (1 given)
TypeError: calculate() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

either require to define a second function (dropping the event argument, or creating a fake one) calling the actual callback.

---

<sub>1. the `*` means store arguments as list, `args` is the name of the parameter and can be whatever you want, but most often `args` by convention.</sub>